# Magento 2 REST API call to get logged in customerID

Tags: node.js, rest, magento, magento2

In reference to this link: [Magento 2 REST API call to get logged in customer ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500559/magento-2-rest-api-call-to-get-logged-in-customer-id?rq=1)

We are working on a similar scenario, where the frontend sits on Magento 2 and logic is written on server side( creating web services) using Node.js and Express.js.  Everything sits on other webspace running  Node.js so the front end sends API calls for requests and server side logic should add products to cart for both guest and customer logged in.

How to differentiate between guest and customer on websites using REST API's?, for now we only managed to create guest cart, create cartid and send items, but we are stuck on fetching cart information for guest if already exists and same for the customer. we are adding product as the guest, but we need to find the difference as to guest and customer - how to fetch current customersID on the website using API's.

Answer (score 0):

It's not sure how you are authenticating customer, the best method would be token based authentication. Where you can easily differentiate between guest and customer.

You can go through this link for Magento token based authentication  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

Hope this helps you to find a way out of your confusion.